# How can I improve this RE to not end at "('"?

Tags: regex

I have this regex

`href=["'](.*?)["']`

And I want to match this entire string but it only matches up to `('` and does not include explore

`href="javascript:openurl('/Xplore/accessinfo.jsp')"`

It also has to match

`href="/iel5/4235/4079606/04079617.pdf?tp=&arnumber=4079617&isnumber=4079606"`

The first link is the only special case, I have been able to match all other cases with the regex I have provided, I just want to somehow exclude the `'` in the middle of the first string.

Comment: Your regexp tries to match as _few_  characters as possible with the middle parentheses. So it stops matching on the first quote/double quote it finds after the initial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have a positive lookahead define the end of the string:

```
^href=("|').*?(?=\1)\1$
```

That way, no matter if its a single or double quote, the second capture group will run till it finds the same single or double quote.

Comment: Thank you, could you please explain what the `(?=\1)` means?

Comment: It's a positive lookahead to match either the double or single quote from capture group 1. Btw, since you want to match the whole string I removed the capture group in the middle and included start and end string ancors @Markimoop

Comment: So, since it captured a double quote first it will try to match with that?

Comment: Exactly =) @Markimoop